# An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist Process.Start() Administrator

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application which has `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`  set in it's app.manifest, so it runs as administrator.

Now i want to start mmc.exe and open dhcpmgmt.msc, which gives me the error

`An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist`

This is my code so far:

```
private static void startProcess(String fileName, String arguments)
{
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    proc.Start();
}
```

And this is how i call it:

```
startProcess("C:\\Windows\\system32\\mmc.exe", "C:\\Windows\\system32\\dhcpmgmt.msc");
```

If i replace this with `startProcess("cmd", "");`, it works fine and the started cmd is indeed started as administrator.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it a local admin account or a AD domain account? Is this running on the same machine as you wish to manage?

Comment: Local admin account and all of it running locally for testing. I just want to start the programs, i don't have an AD in my testing environment.

Comment: Are you running this from the VS IDE? What if you add `proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;`, call the method as `startProcess("dhcpmgmt.msc", "");`, compile and run the executable? And if you ask to open a different snap-in, e.g., `startProcess("secpol.msc", "");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting to open MMC (Microsoft Management Console) using [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0), one receives the error: "An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist." when one runs one's application as a 32-bit process on a 64-bit OS.

[image]

This happens because of the [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector). The documentation states:

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by
> substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64
> recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file
> system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and
> easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file
> system redirection. Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the
> Sysnative alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.

Try the following:

```
private void RunProcess(string filename, string arguments)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        Arguments = arguments,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = filename,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        Verb = "runas",
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename)
    };

    using (Process p = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo })
    {
        //start
        p.Start();
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
string filename = string.Empty;
string arguments = string.Empty;

//environment variable windir has the same value as SystemRoot
//use 'Sysnative' to access 64-bit files (in System32) if program is running as 32-bit process
//use 'SysWow64' to access 32-bit files on 64-bit OS

if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
    //filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32", "mmc.exe");
    filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "Sysnative", "mmc.exe");
    arguments = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32", "wmimgmt.msc");
}
else
{
    filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32","mmc.exe");
    arguments = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32", "wmimgmt.msc");
}

Debug.WriteLine($"Is64BitOperatingSystem: {Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem}; Is64BitProcess: {Environment.Is64BitProcess}");
Debug.WriteLine($"filename: {filename}; arguments: {arguments}") ;

RunProcess(filename, arguments);
```

---

**Update**

**Note: Below are some other possible error messages which can be avoided by using the code above.**

If one uses the following:

- `UseShellExecute = false`

and one attempts to do the following when one's application is running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS:

```
RunProcess(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32", "wmimgmt.msc"), string.Empty);
```

one receives the following error message:
`An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Windows\System32\wmimgmt.msc' with working directory 'C:\Windows\System32'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

If one attempts to do the following when one's application is running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS:

```
RunProcess(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "Sysnative", "wmimgmt.msc"), string.Empty);
```

one receives the following error message:

`An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Windows\Sysnative\wmimgmt.msc' with working directory 'C:\Windows\Sysnative'. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.`

---

If one uses the following:

- `UseShellExecute = true`

and one attempts to do the following when one's application is running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS:

```
RunProcess(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32", "wmimgmt.msc"), string.Empty);
```

one receives the following error message:
`An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Windows\System32\wmimgmt.msc' with working directory 'C:\Windows\System32'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

If one attempts to do the following when one's application is running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS:

```
RunProcess(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "Sysnative", "wmimgmt.msc"), string.Empty);
```

one receives the following error message:
`MMC cannot open the file C:\Windows\Sysnative\wmimgmt.msc...`